# How does trending feature in Highlighted Content Webpart Work in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, highlighted-content-web-part

We have utilized Highlighted Content Webpart in our organization and as a filter we are using Trending. I was wondering how does that feature work and how often does it update and what actions is it checking to qualify content as trending?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no official document to explain the specifications for how the Trending feature works.

I suppose that Trending would indicate relevance to the current user based on popularity and relationships.

More reference:

[Modern SharePoint Web Parts: Highlighted Content web part.](https://lightningtools.com/blog/modern-sharepoint-web-parts-highlighted-content-web-part)

Comment: When will we get the official document on this feature, why is it being treated like a black box. It very important that we know how the feature works internally.

Comment: I am afraid that there is no exact time when the official document comes out.
You could submit the uservoice about the trending feature in the Highlighted Content Webpart.